# Electricity voltage & current

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

Why does current return to its source?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: No current needs not always to go back to the source. E.g. negative terminal of the battery grounded.

Comment: I tried to edit your post to clarify the question being asked. IS this rewording faithful to what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right, your question is "why does current need to return to the same source?" Electrical current is caused by the flow of electrons, i.e. when an electron moves from the shell of one atom to another, then there is a net current flow. However, this causes the ionization of the other atom, which is naturally in a neutral (non-ionized) state. As a result, this newly positively charged ion attracts an electron. The idea of current returning to the same place isn't exactly right - it's that current in must equal current out (see: Kirchhoff's Laws), most easily represented in a circuit by drawing a loop.

Comment: yes you are right